# CUDA is it safe to copy a single element from device memory by array offset?

Tags: c++, memory, cuda, memcpy, data-transfer

```
int main()
{
    int n = 1000;
    float *d_a;
    cudaMalloc(&d_a, n * sizeof(float));

    // do something that gives d_a value;
    int index = rand() % n; // copy index
    float res;
    cudaMemcpy(&res, &d_a[index], sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaMemcpy(&res, d_a + index, sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    // Are the above 2 the same and legal ?
    cout << res << "\n";
}
return 0;
```

So I have the following problem. I need to copy exactly 1 element (random index) from the device array. I don't want to copy the entire array because it'd be wasteful.

So, is the above methods safe and conform to CUDA programming guide?

Comment: "Are the above 2 the same ?" -- yes.

Comment: Thank you. They're the same on CPU, but i didn't know whether it's true for host's pointer to GPU memory. About the main question, is the 2 statement safe to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is no problem with what you have shown.  It is legal and should copy the element you desire from device to host.

Regarding your two methods, they are the same (this is a C++ question, not specific to CUDA).

Comment: I wonder, how does the program knows &d_a[index] is still a pointer to device memory? does cudaMemcpy() performs address translation?

Comment: It doesn't.  What you are doing is varying forms of pointer arithmetic.  Remember, all of the code you have shown in this question is **host** code.  With appropriate steps, you could compile this code directly with a host compiler, such as `g++`.  There is nothing that is terribly CUDA-specific going on here.  The `cudaMemcpy` call is a *library* call, not unlike the behavior you would get using a `memcpy` *library* call.  The interpretation of `&d_a[index]` vs. `d_a + index` is handled entirely by C++ rules.  A pointer is a pointer.  The compiler has no knowledge of host/device.

Comment: But for example, if d_a== 400 (points to address 400), and there's an array int[5] from 404 to 420, then how can the program knows &d_a[2]==408 is a pointer to GPU memory instead of CPU memory? Or does that case never happens?

Comment: Let's assume the value of `d_a` was previously set by `cudaMalloc` such as is happening in your code.  Let's say that `cudaMalloc` returned a value of 400 as you suggest, for the value of `d_a`.  That value of 400 marks the start of an allocation that consists of 1000 `float` quantities, according to your program.  So that allocation would extend from 400 to 400+1000*4 = 4400.  For the range of 400 to 4400, the `cudaMemcpy` call "knows" **at runtime** that it belongs to device memory.   This means the CUDA runtime checks the addresses passed, before using them.

Comment: If you're suggesting that in addition to all that, if you had another (I assume host?) array `int[5]` that is located at 404 to 420, then I would say no, that never happens.  The [CUDA UVA system](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__UNIFIED.html#group__CUDART__UNIFIED) guarantees that.  Prior to CUDA UVA would be a separate case.

Comment: Ohh, so cudaMalloc() also occupies memory address space, just like normal malloc(). I didn't know this detail and always thought that memory allocated by cudaMalloc() doesn't occupy normal address space (other than the pointer)

Comment: Yes the UVA thing is exactly what I was wondering about! I didn't know exactly whether CUDA use unified memory space or not. Thanks!

Comment: CUDA UVA guarantees that the address spaces of host and device (for all devices in the system) are "harmonized" meaning there is no overlap, and a pointer can be (theoretically, anyway) uniquely determined by its value, as to which entity it belongs to.

Comment: There was a CUDA operation model prior to UVA in which these statements didn't hold, and it is still possible to make things work.  Furthermore, let's be clear that none of this has anything to do with the equivalence of `&d_a[index]` and `d_a + index`.  That equivalence is discoverable at compile time and rests entirely on C++, not anything specific to CUDA.  Nothing is known about the host or device association of a pointer at compile time.  A pointer is a pointer.